# When to use method call "()" syntax in Knock.js binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So heres a great way to waste 20 minutes. When binding like this in a foreach loop using knockout.js everything works just fine.

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: LineItems">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-bind="value: Quantity" class="may-frm-grid-input may-frm-grid-input-txt-num" />
    </td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: UnitPriceExTax" class="may-frm-grid-input may-frm-grid-input-txt-num" /></td>
    <td data-bind="text: LineTotalExTax" class="may-frm-grid-val-lbl"></td>
    <td>
        <input data-bind="value: UnitPriceTaxRate" class="may-frm-grid-input may-frm-grid-input-txt-num" />
    </td>
    <td data-bind="text: LineTotalTaxAmt" class="may-frm-grid-val-lbl"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: LineTotalIncTax" class="may-frm-grid-val-lbl"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Note that the bindings are just using the method name not a method call ie. LineTotalExTax not LineTotalExTax()

But outside of a foreach as below:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="may-frm-grid-lbl-right"></td>
        <td class="may-frm-grid-lbl-right"></td>
        <td class="may-frm-grid-lbl-right"></td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: FreightExTax" class="may-frm-grid-input may-frm-grid-input-txt-num" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: FreightTaxRate" class="may-frm-grid-input may-frm-grid-input-txt-num" />
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: FreightTaxAmt" class="may-frm-grid-val-lbl"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: FreightIncTax" class="may-frm-grid-val-lbl"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This seems to create problems. So although the values get bound when binding to computed observables like this:

```
function EoiViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.LineItems = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.QuoteID = ko.observableArray();
            self.CurrencyID = ko.observableArray();

            self.FreightExTax = ko.observable(0);
            self.FreightTaxRate = ko.observable(0);

            self.FreightTaxAmt = ko.computed(function () {
                return (self.FreightExTax() * (1 + (self.FreightTaxRate() / 100))) - self.FreightExTax();
            });
            self.FreightIncTax = ko.computed(function () {
                return  self.FreightExTax() + self.FreightTaxAmt();
            });
            self.TotalExTax = ko.observable(0);
            self.TotalTaxes = ko.observable(0);
            self.TotalIncTax = ko.observable(0);

        }
```

The value returned for:

```
  <td data-bind="text: FreightIncTax" class="may-frm-grid-val-lbl"></td>
```

would be an insanely annoying 100.11110000 for a freightextax of 10 and a freighttaxrate of 1. i.e. it was using "+" as a concantenation operator not an additive operator.

So my question is why? How did I "get away" with no method call syntax in the foreach but not in the bind outside of a loop?

Update:

And i should also add the foreach loop fail to bind is I add in method "()" syntax so clearly its something to do with scope but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with the `()`s. In Knockout, binding to a single observable or computed can be done with or without `()`s. This is because Knockout basically runs `ko.unwrap()` on the binding to get its value.

You're getting the a concatenation problem here because although the observables `FreightExTax` and `FreightTaxRate` were originally assigned numbers, they became strings because they were bounded to an input box. As soon as the values were modified, they were now strings. And this line:

```
return self.FreightExTax() + self.FreightTaxAmt();
```

became a concatenation. A parseFloat() fixes it...

```
return parseFloat(self.FreightExTax()) + self.FreightTaxAmt();
```

Fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/VSZE4/

Comment: Marvellous Thanks. It turned out tho I thought I fixed it I hadn't. Playing around it a bit more I found that reconverting "value" * 1 fixed the problem. So then as per your your suggestion the "real" answer was to parse to some numeric.